# I am in need to log time taken by a AJAX API call in details like below

Tags: jquery, ajax, response

I am in need to log time taken by a AJAX API call in details like below.

I want to log all timing in separate console.log, is there any way we can achieve this?

something like this

```
console.log(Started)

console.log(Queueing)

console.log(Stalled)

console.log(Request sent)

console.log(Waiting for server response)

console.log(Content Download)
```

[image: this is the total response time taken by AJAX request now i only want to print all the value in console.log]

Not able to log all the required details

Comment: For what purpose? This information is already present in your browser dev-tools _Network_ panel

Comment: @Phil The situation is whenever i am opening dev-tools website is getting logout and redirect to login page, in that case required details are not there.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

To log result you firstly need to measure elapsed time like this:

```js
let startedTime = new Date();
// here is your code
let elapsedTime = new Date() - started;
```

To keep your code DRY (acronym for Don't Repeat Yourself) you can meausre time using function:

```js
function logTime(label, action) {
  let startedTime = new Date();
  action();
  console.log(label + " > " + (new Date() - started) + "ms");
}
```

And then you can use this function to log results:

```js
console.log("Starting");
logTime("Quered", query);
logTime("Stalled", stall);
logTime("Request sent", sendRequest);
logTime("Waiting for server response", connectToServer);
logTime("Content downloaded", downloadContent);
```

Comment: can you please provide a fiddle for this as it is showing jQuery.Deferred exception warning for me, and breaking the code too.